# Update MySQL Data with a GET variable

Tags: php, mysql, get

I've created a little login strucuture:

If you had wrote your data into fields you receive a link to confirm the account.
e.g. confirm.php?email=a@a.com
When you visit the link the following code executes:

```
$sql = mysqli_connect("localhost", "name", "password");
mysqli_select_db($sql, "db");
$set_active = "UPDATE `users` SET `active` = 1 WHERE `email` = ".$_GET['email']."";
mysqli_query($sql, $set_active);
mysqli_close($sql);
```

But after that the active-value is still 0 like deafult.

The users table:
email (varchar 100)              active (int 1)
a@a.com                          0

Comment: Prefable: use a prepared statement with placeholder. Otherwise, you need to put quotes around the value, and should also use `mysqli_real_escape_string` to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: user mysqli_error() you will find exact error

Comment: You don't have quotation marks around your email variable.  Try changing it to `'" . $_GET['email'] . "'';`  Also, you should be using prepared statements with MySqli or PDO.

Comment: remove " at last of you query one is extra

Comment: Thanks Kyle now it works. I've also prevented SQL-Injections but I didn't posted the entire code here.

Answer (score 2):

Use a prepared statement:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($sql, "UPDATE `users` SET `active` = 1 WHERE `email` = ?") or die(mysqli_error($sql));
mysqli_bind_param($stmt, "s", $_GET['email']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) or die(mysqli_error($sql));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$set_active = "UPDATE `users` SET `active` = 1 WHERE `email` = '".$_GET['email']."'";
```

You have missed `'` in email. So the query is wrong. to check that do:

```
echo("UPDATE `users` SET `active` = 1 WHERE `email` = ".$_GET['email']."");
```

This will give you an error.

Answer (score 0):

Things get evaluated in double quotes but not in single

change

```
set_active = "UPDATE `users` SET `active` = 1 WHERE `email` = ".$_GET['email']."";
```

to

```
set_active = "UPDATE `users` SET `active` = 1 WHERE `email` = '".$_GET['email']."'";
```